# Check whether a line-segment intersects the perpendicular line draw from a particular point?

Tags: algorithm, vector, geometry

As shown in this image:

[image]

I have a set of line segments.  I want to check which line-segments intersect with the perpendicular line drawn from a given point (x0,y0).

(E.g.: AB passes the check and BC does not.)

The only information I've got is two points of the line-segment, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), and the target point (x0,y0).

Is it possible to derive a simple formula using these three points?

Thanks in advance.

umanga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As background, if you need to, you can read up on [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), its [geometric interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_interpretation), and in particular [scalar projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Scalar_projection).

Define the vectors **v0**=(x0,y0)-(x1,y1) and  **v2**=(x2,y2)-(x1,y1).

Then the intersection point is

(x1,y1) + ((**v0**⋅**v2**)/(**v2**⋅**v2**))**v2**

The intersection point will be on the line segment if the scalar value (**v0**⋅**v2**)/(**v2**⋅**v2**) is between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

For a line AB and a point X, both angles, ABX and BAX must be acute (or right).